# Imagemagick crop and watermark windows

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

Using a batch file in Windows 11 to try and crop and watermark a folder of images, and place them into a new folder named "watermarked".

Not getting any output on this. Any ideas why?

```
@echo off
IF NOT EXIST ./\watermarked mkdir watermarked
FOR %%i IN (./1/*.jpg) DO (
echo "watermarking ./%%i"
convert "./%%i" ^
-gravity East -chop 420x0! ^
-gravity West -chop 420x0! ^
-coalesce ^
-gravity NorthWest ^
-geometry +30+0 null: ./a_watermark.png ^
-layers composite ^
-layers optimize "./watermarked/%%~nxi"
)
```

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`!